# Скорость анимации вложенного элемента отличается родителя

Tags: css, css3, вёрстка, анимация, css-animation

Есть кнопка, в которой помимо текста есть еще и тэг и явно заметно, что скорость анимации вложенного тега значительно меньше, чем скорость анимации всей кнопки и её основного содержимого.

```css
* {
  transition: all 0.1s linear;
  font-weight: bold;
}

button:hover {
  background-color: black;
  color: white;
}
```

```html
<button><i class="icon">svg</i>Текст кнопки</button>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```css
* {
  transition: all 0.1s linear;
  font-weight: bold;
}

button:hover,
button:hover i.icon {
  background-color: black;
  color: white;
}
```

```html
<button><i class="icon">svg</i>Текст кнопки</button>
```

Comment: Хотя на самом деле даже в таком варианте видна микросекундная задержка. Идеальным вариантом оказался следующий код:

    button:hover{background-color:black:}
    button:hover *{color:white;}

И оборачивание текста кнопки в какой-нибудь тег.